# CMake target dependency of external library not found when importing

Tags: c++, cmake

I have two cmake projects, A and B, whereas B depends on A. A is a header only library which links to Threads in its main CMakeLists.txt:

liba/CMakeLists.txt

```
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(liba_liba INTERFACE Threads::Threads)
```

Library A also writes out a package config file using

liba/CMakeLists.txt

```
install(
    TARGETS liba_liba
    EXPORT libaTargets
    ...
)

install(
    EXPORT libaTargets
    NAMESPACE liba::
)
```

So say I install it with

liba/

```
cmake --install build --prefix output
```

Now in library B I consume library A if I provide the prefix path:

libb/build

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/user/dev/liba/output
```

It then seems that libb target has been found. However I get the following error:

```
The link interface of target "liba::liba" contains:

    Threads::Threads

  but the target was not found.  Possible reasons include:

    * There is a typo in the target name.
    * A find_package call is missing for an IMPORTED target.
    * An ALIAS target is missing.
```

Why is this happening?

**EDIT**: When I do a `find_package(Threads REQUIRED` in library B the Threads target is found and everything compiles fine. Which I suppose means the Threads target is available on my system. However, the point is that liba should provide the Threads target transitively?

Comment: Because you use `find_package(Threads)` in your `CMakeLists.txt`, you need to call `find_dependency(Threads)` in your export file. "However, the point is that liba should provide the Threads target transitively?" - While this seems logical on the first glance, CMake simply doesn't how `Threads::Threads` would look on the **target machine**, where your project is installed. Because of that CMake expects you to provide such target.

Comment: @Tsyvarev So this is the idiomatic way to make dependencies available to downstream targets? I'm still not done learning CMake it seems.

Comment: Yes, `find_dependency` is an idiomatic way for export dependencies.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Ok so basically that means I always need to repeat dependencies in find_package and find_dependency of liba in any case?

Comment: Yes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60856992/if-i-find-package-in-cmakelists-txt-must-i-find-dependency-in-my-installed-conf

Comment: @Tsyvarev You really know your way, thx!